# Mobile Application for Restaurants

Tags: arrays, algorithm, data-structures

Design a mobile app which tells nearest restaurants to your current location. Discussion on how restaurants should be stored on database. How should database be searched for restaurants based on current location. How it can be optimized in case of remote areas and dense population areas.

This is a interview question asked in one company.Any suggestions on how to store restaurants in database,How to distinguish between sparse and densely populated areas and how can it be optimized

Answer (score 0):

you can use tags for each restaurant's location, like if a restaurant is situated in hauz khas, then you can use tag hauz khas for that, now whenever any user searches you also know his location so search for its nearby tagged localities in your DB using elasticsearch. now you can perform any kind of operation(preference order, distance etc) you want to as you have a very small list of restaurants